# scala object extends app does not print anything

Tags: scala, program-entry-point

I am learning Scala and as part of the journey I had come across two different ways to write your scala class - one with a main method and other without the main method  but by extending App (earlier **Application** is *deprecated* due to concurrency issues).

I am executing the scripts in Command Line via `scala` executable as `scala <nameOfScript>.scala`. I run **Scala 2.11.7** in **Windows**.

I have no issues when running a scala script/class with a main method.

```
object ObjectWithMainMethod {
    def main(args:Array[String]) = {
            println("Object with a main() method executed..")
    }
}
```

It produces the following output.

```
Object with a main() method executed..
```

But, I don't get the output with its counterpart, which is extending App trait but without the main method.

```
object AppWithoutMainMethod extends App {
    println("AppWithout main() method executed")
}
```

When I run this scala script, it does not print anything. However, when I looked at the complied .class files via *javap* utility, I could see the PSVM (public static void main() method) inside.

Am I missing something? Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "When I run this scala script" - _how_ are you running this? The code looks fine, so the issue is probably with the execution...

Comment: @TzachZohar, I run this using 'scala' executable on the command line as `scala AppwithoutMainMethod.scala`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The same thing works if I run the file without the `.scala` extension. I am not sure the reason behind this.

```
scala AppWithoutMainMethod
```

It produces the following output

```
AppWithout main() method executed
```

Comment: You can specify `scala -howtorun:help` to see how to tell it what to execute. Here, you're letting it guess that you want to run your pre-compiled class, which is the normal behavior of the `java` runner. With the `.scala` extension, it will guess `script`, which means it must examine the script to pick an entry point, as in Scala there is no required correspondence between source file name and public class name.

Comment: This is not an answer; the other reply is an answer. See my comment for why this reply will leave the reader confused. Namely, here you're not running in "script" mode, where the source is recompiled. "Leave off the .scala part" is not how to run a script.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `scala -help` you'll see this comment:

> A file argument will be run as a scala script unless it contains only
>   self-contained compilation units (classes and objects) and **exactly one
>   runnable main method**.  In that case the file will be compiled and the
>   main method invoked.  This provides a bridge between scripts and standard
>   scala source.

This explains exactly what you're seeing - the `scala` command is primarily meant to execute "scripts", or a series of expressions - for quick, interactive evaluation of code snippets. It only runs "applications" (i.e. objects with main method) as a "special case", because it makes sense users will try to use it this way. So:

- When you run `scala ObjectWithMainMethod.scala`, the main method is identified and the command enters this "special case", figuring out that you probably meant for it to work that way
- When you run `scala AppwithoutMainMethod.scala`, even though `App` has a `main` method, this isn't identified as the "special case" but just as a series of expressions, so the main method isn't invoked.

If you compile your classes into `.class` files and run them via `java -cp <classpath> <class-name>` command, the two will produce identical results.

Comment: thanks for your response. However how or when should this script without main method get executed?

Comment: Whatever the books and online materials I have been referring to, almost all of them say that these two are identical (with main method, without main method but extending `App` trait). Isn't it contradictory?

Comment: This was deemed a bug and fixed in 2.11.9, as mentioned in the issue @som-snytt linked.